# sequence of random variables converge to $X$ in probability with all expectation zero, but $\mathbb{E}[X] = \infty$.

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, expected-value

I'm currently working on the following problem:
Construct a sequence of random variables $X_n$ and $X$ such that $X_n \overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow} X$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_n] = 0$ for all $n$ but $\mathbb{E}[X] = \infty$.

I can imagine random variables with infinite expectation like $\mathbb{P}[X] = \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but struggle to see how to construct a sequence that converges to $X$ while meeting the criteria.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb E[|X|] = +\infty$ or $\mathbb E[X] = +\infty$ (i.e. $\mathbb E[X_+] = +\infty$ and $\mathbb E[X_-] < +\infty$)

Comment: I mean $\mathbb{E}[X] = + \infty$, no absolute value. With $\mathbb{E}[X_+]$ and $\mathbb{E}[X_-]$ you mean only positive and negative values of $X$? Never seen this notation.

Comment: It's the positive/negative parts of $X$: $$X_+ = \max(0,X) \\X_- = \max(0,-X)$$ (they are both positive). Normally, you define $\mathbb E(X) = \mathbb E(X_+)- \mathbb E(X_-)$ so that you can revert to expected values of positive random variables. When both $\mathbb E(X_+)=\mathbb E(X_-)=+\infty$, it is ill defined.

Comment: ah thanks, now i remember I've seen that only with the + and - at the top

Answer (score 2):

Take for example:
$$
X_n = \begin{cases}
X & X<n \\
-n\ln n & X\geq n
\end{cases}
$$
with $X$ a Pareto distribution with exponent 1, i.e. it is supported on $(1,+\infty)$ with pdf:
$$
p(x) = \frac1{x^2}
$$
Using:
$$
\mathbb P(X>n) = \int_n^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2} = \frac1n
$$
You can check that:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(X_n) &= \int_1^n \frac{xdx}{x^2}-n\ln n\frac1n\\
&= \ln n-\ln n \\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$
And for large enough $n$:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(|X-X_n|>\epsilon) = \mathbb P(X>n)= \frac1n\to 0
\end{align}
$$
And finally:
$$
\mathbb E(X) = \int_1^{+\infty} \frac{dx}x =\lim_{x\to+\infty}\ln x= +\infty
$$

Essentially, you choose beforehand $X$ which has infinite expected value. You then cutoff its extreme values and "redirect" them to a negative value tuned so that the expected value is zero. You then let the cutoff go to infinity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a Cauchy r.v. $X$ with density
$$f(x)=\frac1\pi\frac1{1+x^2}$$

Define $X_n=X\mathbb{1}_{(0,n)}(X)+X\mathbb{1}_{(-a_n,-n)}(X)$
with $a_n>0$ to be determine so that $E[X_n]=0$:

$$\frac1\pi\Big(\int^{-n}_{-a_n}\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx+\int^n_0\frac{x}{1+x^2}\,dx\Big)=\frac1{2\pi}\Big(-\log\big(\frac{1+a^2_n}{1+n^2}\big)+\log(1+n^2)\Big)=0
$$
that is $\log(1+a^2_n)=2\log(1+n^2)$, and so $a_n=\sqrt{n^2+2n}$

Observe that $X_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} X_+$ a.s, and thus in probability.